# Get database data on the jquery popup box after click on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following is a link which show a popup box after click on it. I place this link to php while () statement. Because I need to edit user details in admin panel.

```
<td width="70"><a href="#" onclick="myfunc1('<?php echo $uid;?>');"  class="big-link2"     
data-reveal-id="myModal2"><input type="button" value="Edit Details" class="button" /></a></td>
```

After click on this link It will show Jquery popup box with a **html form where 12 fields** exist. I want to show data on this field based on `uid` (user_id).

**Ajax function I'm using is following :**

```
function myfunc1(id) {
    id = id;
    $.ajax({        
            url: 'edit_user_details.php',
            type: 'post',             
            data: {'id' : id},
            success: function(response) {
            //$('#edit_user_result').html(response);          
            $('#sent_password_result'+id).html(response);
            setTimeout(function() {
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false); 
            window.location.href = "users.php"; 
            }, 5000 );  
            } 
    });
}
```

With this ajax function I can get response (e.g. first name, last name, age, country, city etc..) as html output without popup box. But How do I place this result to each field on the form?

**Popup form is like that..**

```
<div id="myModal2" class="reveal-modal3" style="width:90%; margin:a auto; color:#FFF;">
<span style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></span>
<table width="400px" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" class="tr" /></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Details" class="submit_button"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**Note: I'm using this plugin for popup box. http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin**

Answer (score 0):

So, why don't you just do exactly what you're doing in your success function but just build your html in your response so that it updates your myModal2.  Then you can call: $('#myModal2').reveal().

For example, your html from edit_user_details.php would look something like this where you pre-populate the values in your form inputs:

```
<span style="float:right; cursor:pointer;"><a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a></span>
<table width="400px" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td>First name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" class="tr" value="<?php echo $myfirstnamevar ?>"  /></td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Details" class="submit_button"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and your ajax success function would look like:

```
 success: function(response) {
   $('#myModal2').html(response); //insert the html into your modal
   $('#myModal2').reveal(); //'reveal' your modal
 }
```

Comment: in edit_user_details.php page I just get all data from mysql database and `echo` it on this page. After `echo` those data i can get all data as html in response page e.g UserDetails.php page. But how can i put those data to the field ? Do you understand what I mean ?

Comment: Do you want to both show the modal AND update the value of the #sent_password_result?  If you just want to show the modal instead, then reformat your userdetails.php to output the html for the modal. To prepopulate a value into an input, you just have to set it's value property in the html. If you want to do both, then it would be easiest if you echo out json from your userdetails.php with the user details to use on your page.

Comment: ok if output the database value as json then how can i input these value to html form field ?

Comment: If your response contains json then in your success function, you'll parse the response object and then just update the values of the form.  For example, if your json object looked like this: { 'fname': 'Jane', 'lname': 'Smith', 'age': '34' }.  Then you'd set the value of the input 'fname' to: response.fname like this: $("input[name='fname']").val(response.fname);